# alternative solution to too many JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There is a table containing all names:

```
CREATE TABLE Names(
  Name VARCHAR(20)
)
```

And there are multiple tables with similar schema.
Let's say:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
  Name VARCHAR(20),
  Description VARCHAR(30),
  Version INT
)

CREATE TABLE T2
(
  Name VARCHAR(20),
  Description VARCHAR(30),
  Version INT
)
```

I need to query description for each name, by following priority:

1. any records in T1 with matching name and version = 1
2. any records in T1 with matching name and version = 2
3. any records in T2 with matching name and version = 1
4. any records in T2 with matching name and version = 2

I want result from lower priority source only if there are no result from higher priority source.

So far that's I've got:

```
SELECT 
N.Name AS Name, Description = 
CASE
WHEN (T11.Description IS NOT NULL) THEN T11.Description
WHEN (T12.Description IS NOT NULL) THEN T12.Description
WHEN (T21.Description IS NOT NULL) THEN T21.Description
WHEN (T22.Description IS NOT NULL) THEN T22.Description
ELSE NULL
END
FROM Names AS N
LEFT JOIN T1 AS T11 ON T11.Name = N.Name AND T11.Version = 1 
LEFT JOIN T1 AS T12 ON T12.Name = N.Name AND T12.Version = 2
LEFT JOIN T2 AS T21 ON T21.Name = N.Name AND T21.Version = 1 
LEFT JOIN T2 AS T22 ON T22.Name = N.Name AND T22.Version = 2
```

It's working, but are there too much `JOIN` here? Is there any better approach?

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25574/1)**

Sample Input:

```
INSERT INTO Names VALUES('name1')
INSERT INTO Names VALUES('name2')
INSERT INTO Names VALUES('name3')
INSERT INTO Names VALUES('name4')
INSERT INTO Names VALUES('name5')
INSERT INTO Names VALUES('name6')

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('name1','name1_T1_1', 1)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('name2','name2_T1_1', 1)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('name3','name3_T1_1', 1)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('name3','name3_T1_2', 2)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('name5','name5_T1_2', 2)

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('name1','name1_T2_1', 1)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('name4','name4_T2_1', 1)
```

Excepted result:

```
--
--  Excepted result:
--  Name      Description
--  name1      name1_T1_1
--  name2      name2_T1_1
--  name3      name3_T1_1
--  name4      name4_T2_1
--  name5      name5_T1_2
--  name6      NULL
```

Comment: If you have multiple tables that contain the same "sort" of things, such that combining them in queries like this makes sense, it's usually a sign that the data model is wrong. This should have been a single table with an additional column that contains the fact or detail that's currently being used to decide which table the row belongs in. I hope you wouldn't have `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree. But that's only a stupid model I build. T1, T2 .. Tn in real world represent for different data source coming from different programs. The only similarity between these tables in real word is they all have a 'Description' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a solution to eliminate the `case` statement and minimize the repetitive part of the query, it requires some joins of it's own of course, so you'd need quite some tables and/or versions to get any real benefit out of it:

```
;WITH
AllDescriptions AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Rank, * FROM T1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS Rank, * FROM T2
    -- UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS Rank, * FROM T3
    -- UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS Rank, * FROM T4
    -- etc
),
Ranks AS
(
    SELECT
        AllDescriptions.Name,
        MIN(AllDescriptions.Rank) AS Rank
    FROM
        AllDescriptions
    GROUP BY
        Name
),
Versions AS
(
    SELECT
        AllDescriptions.Name,
        AllDescriptions.Rank,
        MIN(AllDescriptions.Version) AS Version
    FROM
        AllDescriptions
        INNER JOIN Ranks
            ON Ranks.Name = AllDescriptions.Name
            AND Ranks.Rank = AllDescriptions.Rank
        GROUP BY
            AllDescriptions.Name,
            AllDescriptions.Rank
),
Descriptions AS
(
    SELECT
        AllDescriptions.Name,
        AllDescriptions.Description
    FROM
        AllDescriptions
        INNER JOIN Versions
            ON Versions.Name = AllDescriptions.Name
            AND Versions.Rank = AllDescriptions.Rank
            AND Versions.Version = AllDescriptions.Version
)
SELECT
    Names.*,
    Descriptions.Description
FROM
    Names
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Descriptions
        ON Descriptions.Name = Names.Name
```

Comment: Updated here since I ended up with this solution. After a few tests, I noticed bad performance because `AllDescriptions` is very large/slow. Since [CTEs are essentially disposable VIEWs](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117), I created an [User-Defined Table Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx) for `AllDescriptions` and use CTEs for other `Ranks`,`Versions`,`Descriptions`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query and it will also give you the expected result.

```
SELECT N.name AS Name, 
       Description = 
           CASE 
               WHEN ( t1.description IS NOT NULL ) THEN t1.description 
               WHEN ( t2.description IS NOT NULL ) THEN t2.description 
               ELSE NULL 
           END 
FROM   names AS N 
       LEFT JOIN t1 
              ON t1.name = N.name 
                 AND t1.version IN( 1, 2 ) 
       LEFT JOIN t2 
              ON t2.name = N.name 
                 AND t2.version IN ( 1, 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working as excepted. Say there are two records for 'name3' with different `version` in T1, this query will output both of them. But only the one with version = 1 is excepted. I attached some test data and excepted results.

Comment: When you are saying "'name3' with different version", it means version other than 1 and 2. Right?

Comment: No. I mean there are two rows in T1 like this `('name3','name3_T1_1', 1) ('name3','name3_T1_2', 2)`

Comment: But, you mentioned this condition i.e. "any records in T1 with matching name and version = 2" and as per it result is coming correct. Would you explain your understanding/concern in brief ??

Comment: How can you have 2 rows with Name='name3' in T1 when Name is T1's primary key?

Comment: @JanVanHerck Sorry, my mistake. That's not primary key. I'll edit.

Comment: @Ryan "any records in T1 with matching name and version = 2",
its priority is lower than "any records in T1 with matching name and version = 1". I want result from lower priority source only if there are no result from higher priority source.

Comment: I have execute query in SQL Fiddle and it is giving expected result that you are explaining i.e. first it displays results which has version value '1' and then for version is '2'. Please check this.

Comment: @Ryan There are seven rows in your output, which should be 6. Row 4 `(name3 name3_T1_2)` should not be in the output because we already have a 'description' for 'name3' - Row 3 `(name3 name3_T1_1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select n.name, isnull(d.description,d1.Description) description
from Names n
outer apply (select top 1 t1.Name, t1.Description
             from T1
             WHERE t1.Name = n.name
             order by Version asc   
            ) d
outer apply (select top 1 t2.Name, t2.Description
            from T2
             WHERE t2.Name = n.name
             order by Version asc   
            ) d1
```